# How to troubleshoot old Sql connections with open_tran > 0?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, nhibernate, owin

We have an ASP.NET API web site which connects using NHibernate to a SQL Server.

The problem we are experiencing is that gradually throughout the day, the number of connections to the SQL server creeps up, and there are many connections that do not appear to be returned to the pool.  By this, I mean that if I run the following query:

```
select * from master..sysprocesses s where datediff(minute, s.last_batch, getdate())>10
```

the number of rows returned just keeps climbing.  Nothing in the API should be taking 10 minutes to complete.  And there are connections in there from *hours* ago.

Here's another clue: the `open_tran` column of all these rows has a value of 1.  So it seems to me that somewhere inside the API call, we're creating a transaction boundary, and that transaction is never being closed.  Perhaps DTC may have a hand in this (we sometimes do connect to more than one database in a call).

The thing is, I haven't a clue how to troubleshoot this further.  I've tried running `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` on the rogue spids, and there's nothing consistent between them.

What are some of the anti-patterns/other possible causes that might lead to this behavior?

**Update:** here's how the DB connection is being created.  We're using StructureMap for Dependency Injection.  We create two DB connections on each unit of work: one "normal" connection for regular read/write access, and an "uncommitted" connection that runs in a transaction with "ReadUncommitted" access (we were having a problem with table locking when reading from large tables).

Here's the code from the DI Registry:

```
For<ISession>().Transient().Use(context => context.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
For<ISessionUncommittedWrapper>().Transient().Use(context => new SessionUncommittedWrapper { Session = context.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession() });
```

Then, inside the unit of work middleware, we create a `UnitOfWork` (with a `using` block, of course), which takes an `ISession` and an `ISessionUncommittedWrapper` in the constructor.  In the `Begin()` method, we have:

```
_uncommittedTransaction = SessionUncommittedWrapper.Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

which gets disposed (along with the `ISession` and `ISessionUncommittedWrapper`) in the `UnitOfWork`'s `Dispose()` method.

Comment: You should *NOT* cache the NHibernate session, only the factory. That's one major anti-pattern. Sessions should be treated as `SqlConnection` objects - generated inside `using()` blocks and disposed as soon as possible. You shouldn't try to hold the session or keep it to use as a cache, that's another major anti-pattern for web applications. Finally, never, ever allow a transaction to exit its immediate scope - ie, NO TRANSACTION fields. These are even more dangerous that connections/sessions and should be released immediately.

Comment: Besides, you don't need transactions. NH uses a transaction itself when saving changes. Attempts to wrap entire requests into a single transaction are a very serious bug (not just antipattern).

Comment: To put it another way, all the transaction-per-requests, session-per-request patterns of the early 2000s were abandoned by 2005 because they exterminated any hope of scalability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the problem.

The way I found the problem was by creating a logging table that tracked the creation and disposal of `Session`s, along with the URI of the endpoint called.  By querying all the undisposed connections, I found that in *every* case where the connection was not disposed, the path began with "/signalr".

```
<facepalm>D'oh!</facepalm>
```

Since the OWIN middleware was proactively creating the Sql connections, it was also doing so for SignalR, which in its nature, keeps the transaction open!  So every client that logged in with SignalR was hogging two Sql connections.

I made the appropriate changes to exclude SignalR connections from the middleware, and now we have no more hanging Sql connections.